# Python convert Lists to List of Lists

Tags: python

How can I convert multiple lists such as :

```
 [3,4,5] and [A, B, C] and [X, Y, Z]
```

and convert it into

```
  [[3,A,X], [4,B,Y], [5,C,Z]]
```

It could be done using a for loop but is there a faster way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use zip. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]
list(zip(a,b,c))
# [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip:

```
list(zip(list1, list2, list3))
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work

```
>>> a,b,c = [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[4, 5, 6]
>>> c
[7, 8, 9]
>>> d= [[a[i],b[i],c[i]] for i in range(len(a))]
>>> d
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```